# How to visualize and programmatically work with huge point cloud

Tags: rendering

I have created a quite large point cloud with about 800M RGB points. The exported .ply file is about 12GB large.
The commercial software I used to create it can render the cloud very smoothly on my Ryzen 1800X/64GB/Geforce 1080Ti.

Now, I would like to work with this point cloud - programmatically put trajectories into it, combine multiple clouds, have more control over the point size ...
Expectedly, using PyntCloud in a Jupyter Notebook failed miserably :)

Before I start learning something like Unity, are there any better suggestions? Potree maybe?
Due to my lack of experience, I cannot judge yet where I would have which possibilities for working with the data.

Comment: PS: I did find https://github.com/keijiro/Pcx

Answer (score 1):

Depends how 'deep' you want to go.

With Unity/Unreal doesn't have to be 'programatically' - they do have GUI, you can just load your data with few button clicks. Potentially you could parse/convert your data to readable format [obj might be easiest](https://programminglinuxgames.blogspot.com/2010/09/parsing-wavefront-obj-file-format-using.html) with for eg. python.

So not sure what programming language you have in mind but as you are mentioning some python modules I guess python.

Then you could display it in many different ways.

- [OpenGL](https://pypi.org/project/PyOpenGL/) (there are many Python bindings over the internet, check them out and choose one that suits you best)
- [Matplot](https://matplotlib.org/), [pygraph](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph) and similar also have an ability to plot in 3D
- explore [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) as it is a great python library to deal with this types of datas

And for eg. you could put it all together inside a [QT](https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5/)